# resignFirstResponder Not Responding

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a text field named "fieldPassword" declared as an IBOutlet

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *fieldPassword;
```

I synthesize it later on and then, in an attempt to have the return key dismiss the keyboard, I have:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   fieldPassword.delegate = self;
   [fieldPassword resignFirstResponder];
   [self.view endEditing:YES];

   return YES;
}
```

The problem is that when I run the simulator and hit the return key in the designated text field, nothing happens. Previously, I also had `fieldPassword.delegate = self;` in `-viewDidLoad` and that crashed the simulator with an `unrecognized selector` error.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It makes no assign the text field delegate inside a method that gets called by the delegate. That's code that is never to be reached. Try assigning it in viewDidLoad (showing us the actual crash you get), or in viewDidAppear.

Comment: 1) Do not call both `resignFirstResponder` and `endEditing:`. Just one or the other. 2) In your `textFieldShouldReturn:` method you should call `resignFirstResponder` on the `textField` parameter. 3) Why set the `delegate` property on `fieldPassword` in one of the text field delegate methods? It should already be set.

Comment: And also never trust your simulator within keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `[self.fieldPassword resignFirstResponder];` instead of `[fieldPassword resignFirstResponder];`

Also `self.fieldPassword.delegate = self;` should be in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the delegate earlier, you won't get the delegate callback. Try this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.fieldPassword.delegate = self;
```

You might have been missing the `self` before.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below things

```
  1.Go to xib or storyboard where you have set that your view.

  2.Right Click the TextField.If you click that you can see the 

       Outlets->Delegate with Empty Circle

  3.Just connect with File's  Owner.It is Yellow Color.

       Once you do this,the circle is not empty.It is filled now.

  4.Then go to declaration or .h part


       #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

       @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

 5.Then in .m

       -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField

       {

          [textField resignFirstResponder];

           return YES;
        }
```